# What is obj in MonitorEnter?

Tags: java-native-interface, synchronize

I am not sure what obj is in MonitorEnter JNI function. Is it obj passed as parameter in native function or shared variable which I want to synchronize?
I have a variable called buffer which is shared by two threads.
This is my code.

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_company_com_HelloActivity_setBuffer(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jstring jstr)
{
    char buf[256];

    int len = (*env)->GetStringLength(env, jstr);       
    (*env)->GetStringUTFRegion(env, jstr, 0, len, buf);
    (*env)->MonitorEnter(env, obj); // I don't think this is correct.
    strcat(buffer, buf); // buffer is declared as global char buffer[256];
    (*env)->MonitorExit(env, obj);
}
```

EDIT:
    How about this? syncobj is defined in Activity as static Object and shared with another thread.

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_company_com_HelloActivity_setBuffer(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jstring jstr, jobject syncobj)
{
    char buf[256];

    int len = (*env)->GetStringLength(env, jstr);       
    (*env)->GetStringUTFRegion(env, jstr, 0, len, buf);
    (*env)->MonitorEnter(env, syncobj);
    strcat(buffer, buf);
    (*env)->MonitorExit(env, syncobj);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is exactly the same as in this Java code:

```
synchronized (syncobj) // = MonitorEnter(env, syncobj)
{
  // ...
} // = MonitorExit(env, syncobj)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first snippet is an equivalent of `synchronized(this)`, the second snippet is `synchronized(syncobj)`. But both snippets make sense only if the other thread accessing your `buffer` can see either `this` or `syncobj`. I am afraid that the other thread is a native one. Why else you would create the `buffer` in native code then? If i am correct, then MonitorEnter/Exit is unnecessarily arcane - you could use it but the other native thread would need to hold a global reference to `this` or `syncobj`. Native locking seems like much cleaner solution. You are locking native resource, not JVM resource.

Comment: Thank you. But, I don't understand your answer clearly. I know the first snippet is wrong solution. But, I think the second snippet is right solution. buffer is global. Thread A appends characters at buffer and Thread B takes out characters from buffer. I only showed append part. I created synobj as static in Thread A and passes it to append part. Thread B gets syobj from Thread A and passes it to take out part.

Comment: I don't know what navtive thread means. I created thread by new MyThread() which is extended from Thread in Java.

Comment: So your both producer (A) and consumer (B) on the buffer are Java threads?

Comment: So then yes, first one won't do because for two different threads, `jobject obj` is two different objects so mutual access is not ensured. Question stands, why do you need to create the buffer native when both producer and consumer are Java threads, and even if so, why simple `synchronized native` methods aren't good enough for you.

Comment: Consumer checks input and if there is, it takes out that in the loop. It has to be done very efficiently. So, I put buffer in C language. If buffer were in Java, I had to call JNI function to check buffer. That is the reason. And, producer calls append function and consumer calls takes out function only. Consumer does not call above code snippet. The first snippet is absurd because obj(this) is producer thread itself. The second snippet works good so far.

Comment: Whoa man, google up "JNI overhead" before you think that "putting things in C" means "doing things efficiently"! Do some profiling, measure time. You are very likely **slower** now than if you would do everything in JVM! Remember that JNI is there primarily for things which you absolutely can't do in JVM. A thredsafe string buffer you definitely can.

Comment: To check input, just one line is enough, if (buffer[0] != 0) in C. I read http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jni/html/fldmeth.html#30642. It says that it is much slower to call JNI function from C to Java than Java to C.